# What is appropriate Java Platform in Windows XP?

Tags: java, exe

I created Software Project in java Netbeans 8 and running on JDK 8.My Operating System is 64 bit.And My client Machine running on Windows xp 32 bit operating system.Would it work in xp if i made exe ?

Comment: Strongly depends on how you make the EXE.

Answer (score 2):

> What is appropriate Java Platform in Windows XP?

None really.  Read this: https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/winxp.xml which explains why Oracle no longer supports Java on Windows XP.

Now you can probably find older versions of Java that will run on Windows XP, but you won't be able to get (reliable) security patches any more, either for the OS or for Java.

> Would it work in xp if i made exe ?

It probably wouldn't.  For a start, many of the ways to turn Java code into an exe do it by embedding a JRE inside the exe!

---

Do yourself a favour and upgrade to a PC with a more up-to-date Windows operating system.  Or install Linux on it ... for free.

Comment: but how to add different java platform on netbeans?

Answer (score 0):

You can still install the Java 8 version in windows XP. When you generate the exe file, try to generate with 32bits.

You can do it with Launch4j for example.